# Two denominational array slicing

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a portion of Viterbi algorithm that I want to manipulate. I need to understand the slicing part in this code:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0.6, 0.2, 0.2], [0.5, 0.3, 0.2], [0.4, 0.1, 0.5]])
pi = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.3])
O = np.array([[0.7, 0.1, 0.2], [0.1, 0.6, 0.3], [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]])

states = UP, DOWN, UNCHANGED = 0, 1, 2
observations = [UP, UP, DOWN]

alpha = np.zeros((len(observations), len(states))) # time steps x states
alpha[:,:] = float('-inf')
backpointers = np.zeros((len(observations), len(states)), 'int')

***alpha[0, :] = pi * O[:,UP]***
```

in the last line print out the O[:,UP] what is should give me:
[0.7, 0.1, 0.2] I believe
instead, it gives me:

```
O[:,UP]
Out[15]: array([ 0.7,  0.1,  0.3])
```

I tried to look into this [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation/509295#509295)
I couldn't understand why it changes the last element of the array.

Also, I run this:

```
O[:,UNCHANGED]
Out[17]: array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4])
```

I'm still newbie in python, I need some help

Comment: you are just reading the first (then last) column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the notation for columns and rows.

You print `O[:,UP]` which gives you all the rows and just the "UP"th column (index 0).

Your `O` is:

```
array([[ 0.7,  0.1,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.6,  0.3],
       [ 0.3,  0.3,  0.4]])
```

And `O[:,0]` is

```
         #↓ this column
array([[ 0.7,  0.1,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.6,  0.3],
       [ 0.3,  0.3,  0.4]])
```

where `O[0,:]` would be

```
array([[ 0.7,  0.1,  0.2], #This row
       [ 0.1,  0.6,  0.3],
       [ 0.3,  0.3,  0.4]])
```

---

And just to make the last part clear, `O[:,UNCHANGED]` is `O[:,2]` which is here:

```
                      #↓ this column
array([[ 0.7,  0.1,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.6,  0.3],
       [ 0.3,  0.3,  0.4]])
```

Comment: OOh I got it now, I'm really mixing this up. Thank though. I got the point

Comment: NumPy slicing can be a bit odd depending on what language you are coming from, but after you get used to it, it's awesome. Best luck =)